# AssertJ dynamically check if Optinal is empty or present

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assertj

I'm working with `OptionalAssert` class of AssertJ and I need to implement a JUnit `ParameterizedTest` that will check for presence or emptiness of an Optional instance in a dynamic way:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource(/* values */)
void test_presence(Optional<String> opt, boolean empty) {
    assertThat(opt) // -> .isPresent() / .isEmpty();
}
```

In a non-parametrised test I would use `.isPresent()` or `.isEmpty()` methods to execute the check, but in this case I'd like to apply something like `.isPresent(true/false)`.

I can't find a method like this in the JavaDoc so I'm wondering if there is an alternative approach to this (or should I just deal with an `if/else`?)

**UPDATE**
I know that I could implement something like so (as suggested in an answer):

```
assertThat(opt.isPresent()).isEqualTo(present);
```

but I'd like to maintain a *fluent* approach, and code similar to this:

```
assertThat(opt)
    .isPresent(present) // true/false
    .hasValueSatisfying(...)
    .hasValueSatisfying(...)
    // etc.
```

Comment: I imagine that `@ValueSource` is not what you actually would use as it does not support two method parameters, right?

Comment: @StefanoCordio yes, I actually have a MethodSource

Comment: not sure if it's possible in your case but can you split the parameterized tests in two parameterized tests: one for the empty case and one for the present case? Otherwise I think a `if/else` is a pragmatic solution

Comment: @JoelCostigliola create 2 parametrized test cases (one for present, one for empty), could be a nice approach. Thanks. Anyway I'd like to know if ther's a more "compact" way to achieve this.

Comment: It's not the solution but another technique is to use `opt.ifPresent(value -> assertThat(value).isEqualTo("foo"))` which would execute the given assertions (I put only one in my example but you can add more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean assert instead

```
assertThat(opt.isEmpty()).isEqualTo(empty)
```

You can use two asserts instead of one, but for fluent assert you can use `org.assertj.core.api.Condition`.

```java
  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("t")
  public void test(boolean empty, Object obj) {
    Condition<Optional<Object>> condition = new Condition<>(empty ? Optional::isEmpty : Optional::isPresent,
        "empty=%s", empty);
    assertThat(Optional.ofNullable(obj)).is(condition);
  }

  public static Stream<Arguments> t() {
    return Stream.of(Arguments.of(false, new Object()), Arguments.of(true, null), Arguments.of(true, new Object()));
  }
```

On assertion error following message is shown

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
  Optional[java.lang.Object@28bdbe88]
to be empty=true
```

Comment: @davioooh I've updated my answer, please take a look

Answer (score 1):

You can simply test like this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(/* values */)
void test_presence(Optional<String> opt, boolean present) {
    assertIsPresent(opt, present)
        .hasValueSatisfying(/* condition */)
        .hasValueSatisfying(/* condition */);
        // ...
}

private OptionalAssert<String> assertIsPresent(Optional<String> opt, boolean present) {
    return present ? assertThat(opt).isPresent() : assertThat(opt).isEmpty();
}
```

However, if you have separate logic for when value is present or not, I'd suggest you split the test into 2 separate ones, one for each case. Much cleaner like that